# How do i set the PDU mode of a modem using python sms 0.3 module?

Tags: python, sms, modem

Am using python [sms 0.3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sms/0.3) module to access my modem on com port. Am trying to send an sms but am getting the following error

sms.ModemError: ['\r\n', '+CMS ERROR: 304\r\n']

When i read the Modem error codes, Error code 304 is for PDU mode, am just wondering how do i set the mode using sms 0.3

Am using a USB modem, Huawei model E220.

Gath

Comment: I do not think this library supports PDU mode at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it via the SMS library, but you can do it directly by sending via the serial port to the modem.:
"AT+CMGF=0" sets PDU mode for SMS messages
"AT+CMGF=1" sets text mode for SMS messages
"AT+CMGF?" should give the current setting